# access constant declared in a c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I have

```
template <typename A,
          typename B,
          typename C>
class Template
{
public:
    static const size_t ZONE_X = 0;
    static const size_t ZONE_Y = 1;
...
}
```

What is the most elegant way I to access the static const variables from other templates that in my case are dependency injection or policy to this one? ... or I should just define the constants out of the template?

Comment: you can access by Template::Zone_X in other templates

Comment: in msvc-10 it reports error - 
`error C2955: 'Template' : use of class template requires template argument list`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Template<void,void,void>::ZONE_X
```

Note that, the three `void`s are needed for `Template` given its definition. Of course, you can use other types, e.g. `int` or mixed of them:

```
Template<int,int,int>::ZONE_X
```

or

```
Template<void,int,float>::ZONE_X
```

Comment: And if `Template` has a data member `A m_data;`?

Comment: @PetrBudnik If it is static, the answer should also work. If it's not, you need to create a object, e.g. `Template<void,void,void> obj`, and then use `obj.m_data`.

Comment: I guess, I was not clear. If given `Template` in the rest of the code (marked `...`) has a member `A m;`, you cannot simply instantiate it with `void`. It simply won't compile, unless you have a specialization... Anyway, I think OP has a design problem - one should not be needing to instantiate template just to get a static data member...

Comment: @PetrBudnik Yes, the types are depended on how OP uses them. The answer will work given little info of `Template`. :)

Comment: @gsf Really? I don't know this. Why does `gcc` have such constraint?

Comment: it is annoying, but gcc validates the whole template (in use or not). If the supplied types do not implement the necessary interfaces in methods that obviously are not in use in this case - it will still complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

the argument list part should be taken with to refer the static member  maybe you should not defined it in a template

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
   template <typename A,
          typename B,
          typename C>
class Template
{
public:
    static const size_t ZONE_X = 0;
    static const size_t JOIN_Y = 1;

};

template<typename A>
class Template2
{
    public:
    static size_t get_zone_x()
    {
        return Template<A,A,A>::ZONE_X;
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << Template<int,int,int>::ZONE_X << std::endl;
   std::cout << Template2<int>::get_zone_x() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```